# Haskell function taking a long time to process

Tags: haskell, optimization

I am doing question 12 of project euler where I must find the first triangle number with 501 divisors. So I whipped up this with Haskell:

```
divS n = [ x | x <- [1..(n)], n `rem` x == 0 ]
tri n = (n* (n+1)) `div` 2
divL n = length (divS (tri n))
answer = [ x | x <- [100..] ,  501 == (divL x)]
```

The first function finds the divisors of a number.

The second function calculates the nth triangle number

The 3rd function finds the length of the list that are the divisors of the triangle number

The 4th function should return the value of the triangle number which has 501 divisors.

But so far this run for a while without returning a result. Is the answer very large or do I need some serious optimisation to make this work in a realistic amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use properties of divisor function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Notice that n and n + 1 are always coprime, so that you can get d(n * (n + 1) / 2) by multiplying previously computed values.

Comment: In general, it's a good heuristic in that kind of tasks, to look at the prime factors of the numbers you get - 501 = 3 * 167

Answer (score 2):

It is probably faster to prime-factorise the number and then use the factorisation to find the divisors, than using trial division with all numbers <= sqrt(n).

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a classical way of finding primes, which may be modified slightly to find the number of divisors of each natural number. Instead of just marking each non-prime as "not prime", you could make a list of all the primes dividing each number.
You can then use those primes to compute the complete set of divisors, or just the number of them, since that is all you need.

Another variation would be to mark not just multiples of primes, but multiples of all natural numbers. Then you could simply use a counter to keep track of the number of divisors for each number.

You also might want to check out [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf), which explains why
trial division is way slower than the real sieve.

Last off, you should look carefully at the different kinds of arrays in Haskell. I think it is probably easier to use the ST monad to implement the sieve, but it might be possible to achieve the correct complexity using [accumArray](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputarray/accumArray_f.html), if you can make sure that your update function is strict. I have never managed to get this to work though, so you are on your own here.

Comment: But if you want to build the list of primes as you go along, you will need to check all positive numbers, and not just the triangle-numbers, don't you?

Comment: @Zed: You are absolutely right. Off the top of my head, I can't say which is asymptotically faster, but my gut feeling tells me that my solution would be faster than Jonno_FTW's original one. I base this on the number of divisors which must be found and the fact that addition is *way* faster than division. Cache-optimizing the sieve can also give a significant constant-factor speedup. I once achieve a 12x speedup just by reusing the same small block of RAM. Cache-optimizing Haskell might be hard though.

rawicki's solution looks like it is much better though.

Comment: Actually, the sieve of Eratosthenes is very helpful, if you combine it with rawickis idea. I just tried this in python an it only takes a small fraction of a second to find the solution. Looking at these two ideas will also help the soultion of other problems of project Euler.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using C instead of Haskell, your function would still take much time.

To make it faster you will need to improve the algorithm, using suggestions from the above answers. I suggest to change the title and question description accordingly. Following that I'll delete this comment.

If you wish, I can spoil the problem by sharing my solution.

For now I'll give you my top-level code:

```
main =
  print .
  head . filter ((> 500) . length . divisors) .
  map (figureNum 3) $ [1..]
```

The algorithmic improvement lies in the `divisors` function. You can further improve it using rawicki's suggestion, but already this takes less than 100ms.

Answer (score -1):

Some optimization tips:

- check for divisors between 1 and sqrt(n). I promise you won't find any above that limit (except for the number itself).
- don't build a list of divisors and count the list, but count them directly.

Comment: It should... but it seems you are building a list of the triangle numbers having >500 divisors, and not just looking for the first one. I'm not into Haskell, so I could be wrong here :)

Comment: For each divisor d, 1 <= d < sqrt n, there is another divisor n/d, sqrt n < n/d <= n.

Comment: @Dave Hinton: Correct, but those divisors can be find using a single division.